# What is the default tcp port jfrog.exe uses to talk to Artifactory?

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

Our Artifactory is on a different subnet from Jenkins and Octopus. I need to have firewall rules established for this. We use jfrog.exe to push and retrieve the artifacts as it is much faster than the REST API. What is the default port jfrog.exe uses?

Opening ports 80, 443 and 8080 didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

It uses what you have configured it to use.
See here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-Configuration

If you are configuring it without a port it will use the protocol default, http : 80, https: 443.

By default Artifactory is running port 8081.

Also, if you are using RSA key to authenticate, you might need to open ssh port to Artifactory (This is not very common)
See here:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-AuthenticatingwithRSAKeys

In general, you should open the port your users are using to access Artifactory.